# Specific :Card Layout In Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, cardlayout

I have a quick question that I'm sure has a quick answer but try as I might I just couldn't figure it out.

So I'm writing a game code where I need to display different screens at different times. I don't know how to do this so I decided to practice with a mini-program. In my mini-program I want three screens: Screen 1 has a button that opens Screen 2, Screen 2 has a button that opens Screen 3 and Screen 3 and a button that opens Screen 1!:

With a bit of research, I was able to find out that I could do such with CardLayout. I've gone back and forth on the Internet for the past hour and this is what I could come up with:

```
public class DifferentScreensTester extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
    Container contentpane = getContentPane();

    JPanel cards = new JPanel();
    JPanel screen1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel screen2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel screen3 = new JPanel();
    JButton screen1b = new JButton("Go to screen 1");
    JButton screen2b = new JButton("Go to screen 2");
    JButton screen3b = new JButton("Go to screen 3");



    //constrcutor
    public DifferentScreensTester() {
        super();

        contentpane.setLayout (cl);

        //add buttons to respective screens
        screen1.add(screen2b);
        screen2.add(screen3b);
        screen3.add(screen1b);

        //add screens to content pane
        contentpane.add(screen1, "Screen 1");
        contentpane.add("Screen 1", screen1);
        contentpane.add("Screen 2", screen2);
        contentpane.add("Screen 3", screen3);

        //action listeners
        screen1b.addActionListener(this);
        screen2b.addActionListener(this);
        screen3b.addActionListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() == screen1b) {
            cl.show(screen1, "Screen 1");
        }
        if (event.getSource() == screen2b) {
            cl.show(screen2, "Screen 2");
        }
        if (event.getSource() == screen3b) {
            cl.show(screen3, "Screen 3");
        }

    }




    public static void main(String [] args) {
        //Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        DifferentScreensTester clmain = new DifferentScreensTester();          
        clmain.setSize(400, 400); 
        clmain.setVisible(true); 
        clmain .setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }


}
```

The first run goes off without a hitch. Screen 1 opens automatically with button 2.
[Here's a picture of what I see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5OBO.png)
However, the second I click on the button, I get a terrifyingly-lengthy error message. It's something about calling the wrong parent for CardLayout.

But I've fiddled with my code for the past half-hour and couldn't fix it! Example codes I found line were way too complex for me, a lowly beginner, to even begin to comprehend.

If someone, anyone, can please tell me that's going on and how to fix it, it would be much much appreciated. If you need any extra information, I shall provide it! Thank you!

Comment: `I get a terrifyingly-lengthy error message. It's something about calling the wrong parent for CardLayout` - the actual error message you get show be posted with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's something about calling the wrong parent for CardLayout.

The `show(...)` method needs the panel that uses the `CardLayout`, not the panel you want to switch to.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for a simple working example.

Also you are using an old method:

```
contentpane.add("Screen 1", screen1);
```

The above uses the add(String, Component) method. Read the `Container` API. This method is obsolete you should be using the `add(Component component, Object constraint)` version method:

```
contentpane.add(screen1, "Screen 1");
```

Comment: I did read that particular section. It's not exactly the most helpful. Also, I changed my show command to call "cards" as the parent, but I still get an error.

Comment: @CodingMee, Of course it is helpful. It has working code you can download and test. How is that not helpful? You start with that demo as the working example and then make changes. Even if the tutorial is shows you explicitly how to add the panels to the layout (which you are doing wrong) and how to change the cards with the show(..) method (which you are also doing wrong).

Comment: Helpfulness is subjective. But thanks for trying to help.

Comment: What do you mean thanks for "tyring" to help. I gave you the exact problem and solution!

Comment: `I changed my show command to call "cards" as the parent, but I still get an error` - my answer suggested the "show(...)" method needs the panel that uses the CardLayout. The "cards" panel doesn't use a CardLayout.